# ERROR: Your buildpacks do not contain the heroku/jvm buildpack!Add heroku/jvm to your buildpack

Tags: java, gradle, heroku

I have java project with gradle and spring boot that I want to deploy to Heroku.

I created myApp.war locally using `gradle war` (I have to deploy locally because I'm using a local lib repository). The war have been created with success, but when I tried to deploy to Heroku `heroku war:deploy myApp.war --app appName`, I received the error:

```
 ! ERROR: Your buildpacks do not contain the heroku/jvm buildpack!Add heroku/jvm to your buildpack configuration or run `heroku buildpacks:clear`.
 !        Re-run with HEROKU_DEBUG=1 for more info.
 !    There was a problem deploying to appName.
 !    Make sure you have permission to deploy by running: heroku apps:info -a appName
```

I'm using:

- Java 10
- Spring boot
- Gradle 4
- I have already add heroku/gradle build pack trough the heroku app settings.
- build.gradle

  plugins {
      id 'java'
      id 'idea'
      id 'maven'
      id 'war'
      id 'application'
      id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.6.RELEASE'
  }

  mainClassName = "com.my.app.BootApplication"

  war {
      baseName = 'my-app'
     version =  '1.0.0'
  }

  logger.lifecycle "war.archivePath = $war.archivePath"

  description = """My app description"""

  sourceCompatibility = 10
  targetCompatibility = 10

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
  }

  repositories {
       maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
       maven { url uri('../my-locally-private-repository') }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
      compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
      compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
      compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
      compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.5.11.3'
      compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version:'1.3'
      compile group: 'com.my.app, name: 'private-dependency-1', version:'1.0.0'
      testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
  }
- system.properties

  java.runtime.version=10
- Procfile

  web: java -jar build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar build/libs/*.war

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run `heroku buildpacks:clear` like the error message says. The heroku/gradle buildpack is not used when you push a WAR file.

Comment: I ran `heroku buildpacks:clear --app myAppName` and after I made deploy and it worked. Thanks!